# Exclude user-specified bookmark folders from Firefox URL autocomplete or URL suggestion functions?

Tags: firefox, bookmark

As far as I know, there is currently no way to make Firefox ignore specific bookmark folders for the autocomplete or suggestions functions in the Location Bar (aka urlbar).

The user can either allow all bookmarks as suggestions or none of them.

Is there a Firefox extension that allows the user to exclude multiple bookmark folders from either the URL autocomplete or URL suggestion functions in the Location Bar (or both)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this:

**Solution 1:**

Install the [Bookmarks Folders Locker/Blocker extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/bookmarks-folders-locker/), if the folder is hidden its content is no longer accessible from the search bar.

**Solution 2:**

If it is a small number of bookmarks, you can exclude them one by one with `Shift+Delete`.

Source: [address-bar-autocomplete-firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/address-bar-autocomplete-firefox#w_removing-autocomplete-results)

Comment: Thanks Zorro.  Upvoted.  For the extension you mentioned, can a folder be hidden without requiring a password?

Comment: Unfortunately not available, but that's a good feature to add.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  By any chance, are you the developer?

Comment: No i'm not the developer, you can try its Support Email.