# Simple method to store additional set of bookmarks for Firefox browser

Tags: windows, offline, firefox, bookmark

I often come across interesting websites while browsing with Firefox.  These are sites that I may, or may not, have time to go back to view.

I don't want to add these sites to the regular Firefox bookmarks because then they will appear in the location bar suggestions.  (I could turn off bookmarks for location bar suggestions, but I want my *regular* bookmarks to still appear.)

I wind up just keeping a text file with all these URLs.  It gets unmanageable and chaotic very quickly.  Plus, cutting and pasting into the file is tedious.

Is there a Firefox extension, *or other solution*, to have essentially two sets of bookmarks: one that is used by for location bar suggestions, and one that is not.

Requirements:

- Must be offline (does not store bookmarks "in the cloud")
- Must handle thousands of bookmarks (acceptable limit is about 5000)
- Gratis or very low cost
- Windows compatible

Not needed:

- Encryption
- Passwords

Already tried:

- [Save-To-Read](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/save-to-read/) - Bookmarks still appear in location bar suggestions.  Also difficult to remove bookmarks.

Comment: I guess [ScrapBook](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/scrapbook/) will not be the best match, as it stores the entire page instead of just bookmarks? That's the first thing which came to my mind …

Comment: Why do they need to be bookmarks? What functionality do you need from them? What's wrong with exporting them as urls?

Comment: Is this different from the one you asked before? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19821/exclude-user-specified-bookmark-folders-from-firefox-url-autocomplete-or-url-sug

Comment: I forgot about that one... wrote it 6 months ago. :-)  This question is similar, but allows for different types of solutions.  The functionality of a bookmark must include storing a URL that, when clicked, opens a web site.

Comment: @Izzy Right, ScrapBook will not work because it stores all the page data.  It's a great extension though!

Comment: Do you want to make this for Chrome too? Otherwise I'll post a new question for Chrome.

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples No thanks. Look forward to your question.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I've just updated my answer (being nudged to it for *Easy Copy)* Are you still undecided, or is your issue solved? I see no accepted answer here :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy.  I'm still undecided.  I haven't had a chance to figure out what will work best yet.

Answer (score 3):

When I read your requirements correctly, a combination of two Firefox addons could do the job:

**[Markdown Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/markdown-editor/)** allows you to open/create, edit, and save *Markdown* documents – using a syntax you're already familiar with from *Stack Exchange*. This would include e.g. nested lists and hyperlinks:

[image: Markdown Editor] [image: Markdown Editor]
<sup>*Markdown Editor* (source: [Mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/markdown-editor/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the second screenshot shows, the addon's *split view* feature would allow you to "click" those links. To make "capturing" links easier, I'd recommend a second addon:

> **[CoLT](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/colt/)** (short for "Copy Link Text") makes it easy to copy either a link's text, or both the link text and its URL in a format you specify. This non-invasive extension simply appears as context menu items when you right-click a link. Fully customizable!

[image: CoLT] [image: CoLT]
<sup>*CoLT* (source: [Mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/colt/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I use *CoLT* myself for years already – and I use it a lot in a similar way as I'm suggesting here: to insert links into Markdown documents (only that most of those Markdown "documents" are answers on SE sites), so I can at least vouch for this part.

> **Edit:**
>
> As [akavel pointed out in the
> comments](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26295/simple-method-to-store-additional-set-of-bookmarks-for-firefox-browser/26300?noredirect=1#comment43318_26300), there's also **[Easy
> Copy](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/easy-copy/)** –
> which somewhat acts like "CoLT on steroids" (much more configurable
> and feature rich). Make your own choice here :) For example, with Easy
> Copy you can [configure](https://sites.google.com/site/smokyinkproductions/easy-copy/how-it-works#TOC-Variables) to get a selected fragment of text from a
> website into clipboard too, using the following snippet:
>
> ```
> * [%page_title%](%page_url%) (%date%)
>
>     > %selection%
> ```

Now let's see how my combination matches your requirements:

- **Must be offline (does not store bookmarks "in the cloud"):** Check.
- **Must handle thousands of bookmarks (acceptable limit is about 5000):** you didn't specify across how many documents they can be split, so: Yes, at least when spread about several documents :) Not sure if the editor has a limit – and if, where it lies.
- **Gratis or very low cost:** Gratis, but donations accepted (both addons)
- **Windows compatible:** I cannot test that currently – but at least for *CoLT* the answer is a definitive yes (have used it on Windows already when at my customers' places)
- **The functionality of a bookmark must include storing a URL that, when clicked, opens a web site:** Yupp, see "split view".

**Conclusion:** If it's acceptable to use two addons to accomplish the task, these two should do. If not, *CoLT* could be substituted by (*Easy Copy* and/or) additional handiwork :)

Comment: Thanks Izzy!  That's a clever combination.  I appreciate it.  I'll give it a try and see how it works out.  I think the number of clicks and cursor movements could make it a bit cumbersome, but it is definitely worth trying.  I'm open to other innovative solutions as well.

Comment: It's definitely not as easy as the "usual bookmark manager". But given your requirements, it's hard to find a good fit: bookmark manager either work with the built-in bookmarks, or store in the cloud (e.g. Pocket). I know there's a "bookmarklet" for ownCloud's bookmark app, but installing ownCloud just for that would be a little overkill. What's left requires a few more clicks then – unless someone can automate it somehow. Btw: The above is almost what I do with parts of my bookmarks – only that I use a separate editor ;)

Comment: Exactly! Right now I've been using a separate editor as well, but it is clunky to switch back and forth, cutting and pasting.  Ideally, I would like either (1) something that adds another integrated bookmark system into the browser, or (2) uses the browser's existing bookmarks system and just excludes a few folders from location bar suggestions.

Comment: Afraid neither 1 nor 2 exist – but I'm gladly taught otherwise.

Comment: Myself as well! :-)

Comment: Instead of CoLT, I found [Easy Copy](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/easy-copy/) more featureful: I configured it to copy the title+link as a markdown bullet item, and also with the currently selected fragment of the page as a quote,

Comment: @akavel that indeed looks like CoLT on steroids! Even has the `%url_full_path%` I've begged the CoLT dev for years ago (and is still not there). Mind making that an answer? Ping me back after that, and I'll upvote!

Comment: @Izzy feel free to steal it for merging into your answer, I don't care about the karma points very much. Unless you have some reasons why you don't want to edit, then prod me again and I'll try to compose something.

Comment: @akavel Ah, you might have a point here – my answer has 2 components, so *Easy Copy* on its own wouldn't make that much sense :)