# Additional bookmark button in Chrome-based web browsers

Tags: chrome, bookmark

I would like to ask the question [Simple method to store additional set of bookmarks for Firefox browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/26295/14867), but for the Chrome-based browsers instead of the Firefox browser.

> I don't want to send certain webpages to the regular browser bookmarks because then they will appear in the location bar suggestions.  (I could turn off bookmarks for location bar suggestions, but I want my *regular* bookmarks to still appear.)

(I paraphrased)

Is there a software that makes a private set of bookmarks that can be controlled from a web browser?

Requirements:

- Must be offline (does not store bookmarks "in the cloud")
- Must handle thousands of bookmarks (acceptable limit is about 5000)
- Gratis or very low cost
- Windows compatible

Not needed:

- Encryption
- Passwords

Already tried:

- [Save-To-Read](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/save-to-read/) - Bookmarks still appear in location bar suggestions.  Also difficult to remove bookmarks.

Comment: If I'm understanding your intent correctly, it is to ask the same question I asked, but for the Chrome browser.  I added that information to make it clear.  If I'm mistaken, please correct my edit! :-)

Comment: @rockpaperlizard Well I intended it to be browser agnostic if that's allowed. It's fine with the edit though, because I guess that would overlap with your question

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I would just say "everything except Firefox"?

Comment: Lol... that's what I had at first, but it sounded weird.  I think specifying a certain class of browser is important, so I made it *Chrome-based*.  Does that work for you?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Yes

Answer (score 2):

## [chrome-pseudobookmark](https://github.com/engen0/chrome-pseudobookmark), For Chrome

I wrote this Chrome extension. It's very simple (especially the v1 release, only ~700 bytes) and easily customizable through the source code.

It creates an alternative bookmarking mechanism and is probably best used as a temporary holding space because it's faster to use than normal bookmarks.

#### Successes:

1. Gratis
2. Windows compatible
3. Works offline

#### Failures:

1. Only supports 512 items

   - But if you change `chrome.storage.sync` to `chrome.storage.local` in the source, you could have unlimited storage.

#### Other positives:

1. There's no possibility for duplication.
2. The interface can be tweaked for custom export options.

> This Chrome extension will create an additional Add Bookmark button with its own separate storage location.
>
> Ctrl+Shift+A bookmarks the active page.
>   Ctrl+Shift+E opens the options page.
>
> Press the toolbar button to bookmark the page.
>   The button disappears on bookmarked pages.
>
> ### Options Page
>
> - Ctrl+A inverts item selection.
> - The options page presents bookmarked URLs as hyperlinks.
> - Click/click-twice to select/deselect items.
> - Pressing the del key, triggers the delete function of selected items.
>
>   - **One** confirmation dialog will appear before permanent deletion.
> - There's an import/export function. It works with item selection. Import works with JSON. Export works with JSON/markdown.
>
>   - **JSON Format:** `{url : {'favicon': faviconurl, 'title': title}}`
> - There's a delete button.
> - There's an invert selection button.
>
> ### Notes
>
> - I don't think extensions like this should be used for maintaining browsing data. Only for producing quick lists.
> - It doesn't have folders.
> - I might write a python component that duplicates the extension by changing its name and color scheme, to provide multiple toolbar buttons and a folder type functionality. That's only if the Chrome API doesn't support multiple activepage buttons.

### The toolbar button:

[image]

### The options page:

[image]